# Error when trying to validate recipe in server-side: iOS receipt validation error 21002

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, swiftystorekit

I have InAppPurchase set in my app using **SwiftyStoreKit** and im trying to validate my receipt.
In order to do so, im fetching it, and sending it to Apple.

I know thats not the right way to do it, but im just testing. If i make it work ill do it in the server-side. Anyway, the problem is the response is always **21002**, witch, according to Apple, means: **The data in the receipt-data property was malformed or missing.**
But when i verify my receipt using SwiftStore method, it works.

Here's the code im using to fetch the receipt and sending it to apple (note:CarregaDados.callMethodJson it just a function with an Alamofire call inside)

```
SwiftyStoreKit.fetchReceipt(forceRefresh: true) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let receiptData):
                let encryptedReceipt = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
                let parametros = ["receipt-data" : encryptedReceipt,
                                  "password" : "XXXXXX",
                                  "exclude-old-transactions" : true] as [String : Any]
                CarregaDados.callMethodJson(.post, parametros: parametros, 
                             url: "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt", 
                             nomeCache: "", onCompletion: { (response) in
                    print(response)
                })

            case .error(let error):
                print("IAP: ERROR: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

That always returns **21002**. But when i check it using SwiftyStoreKit, it works and returns me all the info i need:

```
let appleValidator = AppleReceiptValidator(service: .production, sharedSecret: "XXXXXX")
SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt(using: appleValidator, forceRefresh: false) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let receipt):
        print("Verify receipt success: \(receipt)")
    case .error(let error):
        print("Verify receipt failed: \(error)")
    }
}
```

So i dont know whats the problem.

Comment: Should the `receipt-data` be json encoded POST data instead of a query parameter?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, that was the problem! I figured it out but forgot to post here. But thanks anyway !

Comment: @GustavodePaivaCaiafa can you please share the code with me, because i have the same issue of getting 21002 error.

Comment: did you get the solution?